# What is the difference between 把握and 掌握in Chinese

Tags: translation, grammar, meaning, difference, expressions

In college we were asked that questions and I couldn't get any answers till now

Answer (score 2):

They are similar but have slightly different meaning.

把握 is used to express the idea of holding or grasping something. Most of the time, it was used to describe a sense of control something, for example, 他把握住了这次机会 means: He grasped this opportunity.

掌握 is used to express understanding something, be able to do something, or be professional on some area, like ability or knowledge. for example: 他掌握了这项技术 means he has mastered this technology.

Answer (score 1):

把握 is about expressing confidence in something.

- 對這件事我很有把握 - I am very confident in this matter.

掌握 is about having control over something, which also means "grasp" and "master".

- 這件事你掌握的很好. - You have very good control of this matter.
- 對已掌握了這件事的起因. - I've already grasped the cause/origin of this matter.
- 這件事你掌握了多少? - How much you have mastered/grasped this matter? Also, How much control do you have on this matter?

Answer (score 1):

Who 把握 something sounds like implying he/she's the **decision maker**, controls the direction of some big deal (may be not really big, could be his/her own life, or the progress of a game).

掌握 is more on having some technology, resources, particular thing, expressing someone does have it, implying he/she may (but not necessarily directly, immediately) impact something else **with that thing**.

that's my sense as a native Chinese speaker, hope this helps.